# Proof of The Mean Value Theorem

Tags: calculus

I find the proof of the Mean Value Theorem not intuitive because it uses Rolle's theroem on an auxiliary function.I am sure that there must be another proof which is longer and intuitive but I can't find it in any calculus or analysis book.I wonder if anyone can show  me such a proof or perhaps tell me where I can find one that doesn't use Rolle's theorem or at least is more intuitive (perhaps the original proof).

Comment: Well, Rolle's theorem is a particular case of Lagrange's mean value theorem. Hence the two statements are actually equivalent.

Comment: Would the following argument suit you: Given $f$ on $[a,b]$ there has to be a point $c\in\ ]a,b[\ $ where $f$ deviates most from its linear interpolation between $a$ and $b$.

Comment: The author of the popular proof of the MVT is [Ossian Bonnet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pierre_Ossian_Bonnet). His proof is shown for the first time by J.A.Serret in his _Cours de Calcul Différentiel et Intégral_ (1868) quoting Bonnet but without producing a work of his (in fact this doesn't exist).

Comment: It is less known that E.Galois (!) used the same idea of auxiliary function in a writing published in Gergonne's _Annales_ in December 1830 [link](http://archive.numdam.org/ARCHIVE/AMPA/AMPA_1830-1831__21_/AMPA_1830-1831__21__182_0/AMPA_1830-1831__21__182_0.pdf) pp. 182-183: are there sufficient grounds for a quarrel about priority ?

Answer (score 4):

Lagrange's Mean Value Theorem is nothing but a tilted version of Rolle's Theorem. If the proof you have does not include a drawing, make some drawing for yourself and then it should be clear where the auxiliary function is coming from.

As for the original proofs, it is highly unlikely that the original will be easy to read. The notation will be very different than what you are used to (not to mention that it will be in French) and the standards of rigor completely different. There is a lot to learn from the original work of the great masters of the calculus but I don't think that is what you are looking for right now.

Answer (score 3):

Let $f$ satisfy the hypotheses of the MVT on the interval $[a,b]$. Define $g(x):=f(x)-\frac{f(a)-f(b)}{a-b}x$

**Case 1:** $g$ attains its maximum and minimum at $a$ and $b$. Then $g$ is constant. In this case we get $0=g'(x)=f'(x)-\frac{f(a)-f(b)}{a-b}$ at every point in $[a,b]$.

**Case 2** If the maximum or the minimum is attained at an interior point $c$, then $g'(c)=0$. Therefore $f'(c)=\frac{f(a)-f(b)}{a-b}$.